# SQL Error, returns blank result

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2003

I am having trouble with my sql query it gives me an error that says Join Expression not supported

here is my sql

```
SELECT [course code] & " - " & [Year level id] AS [Course&Year],
tblRegistrationInfo.[Student ID], tblStudent.[ID Number], 
[qryCharges(All)bong].AccountTitle AS Fee,
-IIf(IsNull([qrypayment(all)bong].[amount]),
0,
[qrypayment(all)bong].[amount]) AS [Amount Paid],
[qrycharges(all)bong].[sumofAssessment]-[amount paid] AS Balance,
[Due]+MyRoundAccount([due],5) AS [Amount Due],
IIf([qrycharges(all)bong].[accounttitle]<>"School fee",
[qrycharges(all)bong].[sumofAssessment]-([amount paid]),
IIf([qrycharges(all)bong].[sumofAssessment]*[Percent Charge]-([amount paid])<=0,
0,
[qrycharges(all)bong].[sumofAssessment]*[Percent Charge]-([amount paid]))) AS Due,
tblTerm.Term,
[Last Name] & ", " & [Given Name] & " " & Left([Middle Name],1) & "." AS Name,
qryStudentScholar.Scholarship, tblCourse.[Course ID],
tblRegistrationInfo.[Year Level ID], [qryCharges(All)bong].SumOfAssessment    
FROM tblPercentCharged 
INNER JOIN tblTerm ON tblPercentCharged.[Term ID] = tblTerm.[Term ID], tblStudent 
RIGHT JOIN (tblCourse 
INNER JOIN (tblCSSHeader INNER JOIN (((tblRegistrationInfo LEFT JOIN qryStudentScholar ON tblRegistrationInfo.[Student ID] = qryStudentScholar.[Student ID]) 
INNER JOIN [qryCharges(All)bong] ON tblRegistrationInfo.[Student ID] = [qryCharges(All)bong].[Student ID]) 
LEFT JOIN [qryPayment(All)bong] ON ([qryCharges(All)bong].[Student ID] = [qryPayment(All)bong].[Student ID]) AND ([qryCharges(All)bong].AccountTitle = [qryPayment(All)bong].[Account Title])) ON tblCSSHeader.[CSS Header ID] = tblRegistrationInfo.[CSS Header ID]) ON tblCourse.[Course ID] = tblCSSHeader.[Course ID]) ON tblStudent.[Student ID] = tblRegistrationInfo.[Student ID]

WHERE (((tblCourse.[Course ID])=[Forms]![frmPrintFinancialAssessment]![c79])
AND ((tblRegistrationInfo.[Year Level ID])=[Forms]![frmPrintFinancialAssessment]![c81]) 
AND ((tblPercentCharged.[Term ID])=[Forms]![frmPrintFinancialAssessment]![cboTerm]))

ORDER BY [course code] & " - " & [Year level id],
tblRegistrationInfo.[Student ID],
tblStudent.[ID Number];
```

Either it gives an error or just displays the page headers with no data

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: MySQL or MS-Access SQL?

Comment: You are using Ms-Access Query in sqlserver

Comment: i am currently using ms-access 2003

Comment: 1. Is `Join Expression not supported` the full error message?  2. If you try to switch from SQL view to datasheet view, after the error message there should be something selected in the SQL, this indicates where Access found the first error. Which part is this?

Comment: Also try to simplify the query as much as possible, as long as it keeps showing the error. [mcve]

Comment: it is the full message sir andre, from sql view, when i switch to datasheet view if displays a blank table, but if i try to recreate the query, it gives me that error, supposedly it will redisplay the same output right?

Comment: Did you write that SQL by hand, or is it automatically created by the query editor? i.e. can you switch to query design view without errors?